# Lagrangian multipliers and duality

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I am working on an constraint optimization problem with inequalities like the following:

Maximize $f(\mathbf{x}) = 1 - x_1^{2} - x_2^{2}$ by giving that $g(\mathbf{x}) = x_1 + x_2 >=1$.

The usual steps are to create the Lagranging $L(x, \lambda) = f(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda g(\mathbf{x})$ and write down the KKT conditions, stationary, primal, and dual feasibility as well as complementary slackness and solve. I am a bit confused since I can use the KKT conditions to calculate the derivatives over $x_1, x_2$ and also the complementary slackness and come up with values. So I do not need to calculate the dual in this case.

But when should I make use of the dual lagrangian and how can I do it in my case? Is it that I need to solve over $\partial L/ \partial \mathbf{x}$ and then replace over $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your problem does not have any solution because taking one of the variable, e.g. $x_1$, to $-\infty$ we have $f \to -\infty$.

Second, KKT conditions are in general only *necessary* optimality conditions (e.g. if the problem is non-convex). This means: **if** $x^*$ is a solution then there exist dual variables $\lambda^*$ that, together with $x^*$, satisfy the KKT conditions, given that your problem satisfies some further assumption such as the Slater's qualification constraints. (Note also that in your case $x^*$ does not exist so the "if" does not happen.)

Finally, regarding your main concern:

> I am a bit confused since I can use the KKT conditions to calculate
> the derivatives over $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and also the complementary
> slackness and come up with values. So I do not need to calculate the
> dual in this case. But when should I make use of the dual lagrangian
> and how can I do it in my case?

In short: **If we can solve the KKT, why do we need the dual function at all?** I'm supposing here that our problem is convex and satisfies the Slater's conditions.

The answer simply lies in the word "**if**". If we can solve the KKT, then that's great, we don't need to care about the dual function. **In practice, however, the KKT system often cannot be solved easily/analytically.** In this case, one can solve the dual problem **numerically** (if it's easier to solve than the primal) to obtain $\lambda^*$ and then recover the primal solution by solving $x^* = \arg\min_x L(x,\lambda^*)$. This is a typical routine in convex optimization, and it should be noted that there are also methods that numerically solve both the primal and dual problems at the same time, called *primal-dual methods*.

Let me know if you have further questions.

**Update:** Per OP's request, I show below how to apply the above routine to the following corrected (and convex) problem:
$$\max_x 1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 \quad \mbox{s.t. } x_1 + x_2 \ge 1.$$

There are a few steps.

1. Re-write the problem into the canonical form for convex problems:
   $$\min_x f(x) \quad \mbox{s.t. } h(x) \le 0,$$
   where $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1$ and $h(x) = 1 - x_1 - x_2$ are both convex. Strong duality holds because the Slater's condition holds: $\exists x: h(x) < 0.$
2. Find the dual function $g(\lambda) \triangleq \inf_x L(x,\lambda)$ where $L(x,\lambda)$ is the Lagrangian with $\lambda \ge 0$:
   $$L(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \lambda h(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1 + \lambda(1 - x_1 - x_2).$$
   To minimize $L(x,\lambda)$ with respect to $x$, it suffices to set the derivatives with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ to $0$, which gives $x_1=x_2=\frac{\lambda}{2}$. Therefore
   $$g(\lambda) = \inf_x L(x,\lambda) = L((\lambda/2, \lambda/2),\lambda) = -\frac{\lambda^2}{2} + \lambda - 1.$$
   Thus, we have found the dual function.
3. We maximize the dual function to find $\lambda^*$:
   $$\lambda^* = \arg\max_{\lambda \ge 0} g(\lambda).$$
   You can take the derivative of $g(\lambda)$ and set it to $0$ to find $\lambda^*$, or just notice that $$g(\lambda) = -\frac{\lambda^2}{2} + \lambda - 1 = -\frac{1}{2}(\lambda - 1)^2 - \frac{1}{2} \le -\frac{1}{2},$$
   and observe that the maximum value of $g(\lambda)$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$, attained at $\lambda^* = 1$.
4. Finally, we recover the primal solution by solving
   $$x^* = \arg\min_x L(x,\lambda^*),$$
   where $L(x,\lambda^*) = L(x,1) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - x_1 - x_2$. Again, by setting the derivatives with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ to $0$, or by completing the squares, we easily obtain $x_1^* = x_2^* = \frac{1}{2}$.

Conclusion: the solution to our original problem is $x^* = (1/2, 1/2)$.

Comment: But how can I perform my dual in this case, my question is more about the performed steps I need do not just in this specific case. I modified it a bit, Still I can solve using KKT, but how can I derive the dual in this case and calculate my parameters $\mu$.

Comment: @JoseRamon As I said above, your problem does not have a solution. Why do you want to still look for one?

Comment: Is it the same for my modified case? I want to be sure about how do we solve in case we need to calculate the dual form. What are the necessary steps?

Comment: @JoseRamon You should apply the above routine to convex problems only. Otherwise there's no guarantee on the solution. There exist duality theories for nonconvex problems but I guess that's not what you are looking for. In the current (modified) form, your problem is not convex, and still does not have a solution (let $x_1\to +\infty$ for example). An example of convex problems is to minimize $x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1$.

Comment: My mistake, I meant from beginning maximization and not minimization.

Comment: @JoseRamon Alright. I'm updating my answer to add that.

Comment: @JoseRamon See the update.

Comment: ok, one confusion your solution seems to be correct but one last clarification: $x1_= x_2 = \lambda /2$ but then how you calculate the $g(\lambda)$ isn't it that we solve for x_1 and x_2 and the replace their values to the primal?

Comment: @JoseRamon We solve $x_1$ and $x_2$ with respect to $\lambda$ and replace their values in the Lagrangian, not the primal. I think it's clear enough in my answer.

Comment: I am still confused, why not in the $L(x, \lambda)$ and you directly add it in $g(\lambda)$ I am not sure why the $\inf$ symbol as well?

Comment: @JoseRamon Sorry I don't understand where you are confused at. Could you add more detail? The operator $\inf$ is the same as $\min$ when the minimum exists. You can replace $\inf$ with $\min$ in the above if that makes reading easier for you.

Comment: In the beginning you have $L(x, \lambda) = x_1^{2} + x_2^{2} - 1+ \lambda(1-x_1 - x_2) $ and from KKT we can solve: $x_1 = x_2 = \lambda / 2$. Then, I guess the next step is to derive $L(x, \lambda)$ over $\mathbf{x}$ which is equal to $\{x_1, x_2\}$. It is not really obvious to me why this $g(\lambda) = \inf_x L(x,\lambda) = L((\lambda/2, \lambda/2), \lambda)$ holds though.

Comment: @JoseRamon In Step 2 we find the dual function $g(\lambda)$. By definition $g(\lambda) = \min_x L(x,\lambda)$, i.e. for each value of $\lambda$ (fixed), we minimize $L(x, \lambda)$ over $x$ to obtain an optimal solution $x^*(\lambda)$ (because for each $\lambda$ we have an optimal solution, the latter is a function of $\lambda$), then the dual function is $L(x^*(\lambda), \lambda)$ (which depends only on $\lambda$). In your example, $x^*(\lambda) = (\lambda/2,\lambda/2)$.

Comment: When we optimize over $\mathbf{x}$ there are two partial derivatives one for $x_1$ and one for $x_2$ when $\partial L(x,\lambda) / \partial x_1 = 2x_1 - \lambda$ and $\partial L(x,\lambda) / \partial x_2 = 2x_2 - \lambda$, so am still unsure how we can come up with that solution.

Comment: @JoseRamon What will you obtain when you set those derivatives to 0?

Comment: $x_1 = \lambda / 2$ the same for $x_2$.

Comment: @JoseRamon So what will the dual function become?

Comment: Then should we like $ = \lambda^{2} /2 - 1 + \lambda(1 - \lambda) $. ok you are right. Super thanks!

Comment: @JoseRamon Check your calculations again.

Comment: @JoseRamon You are welcome!